# Customize the google signin button : Change button color to red g+ login IOS SDK

Tags: ios

I want to customize the google signin button in my IOS application.

By default it is in white color and also there is one method  _signInButton.colorScheme  in which there are two color scheme white and blue.

[image: whiteloginbutton]

How can I change color of button to red ?

[image: redloginbutton]

Also how can I set language of button to Arabic without changing my device

language ?

Comment: why don't you take button image and sign in with custom button

Comment: [Can I edit the text of sign in button on Google?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46213682/1306419) answer solves your issue of language etc. Feel free to improve upton it.

Answer (score 2):

Red color which you want to achive is already provided by google.

Please check this [google-sign-in-button-branding-guidelines](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines#google-sign-in-button-branding-guidelines)

[image]

And for changing the text of **Sign in with Google** please check this. you need to change it in .plist file.

[how-to-change-title-of-google-plus-sign-in-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783735/how-to-change-title-of-google-plus-sign-in-button)

Answer (score 0):

Use custom button in your view and set background image of that button. Then on touchUpInside action of that button call **[btnGoogleLogin sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];** where **btnGoogleLogin** is the object of **GIDSignInButton**. For text in Arabic language use custom button with color only and put text on it.